# Windows 8.1 overview view

Tags: windows-8.1

I have been using Fedora linux (running Gnome shell) up to now and have grown to love the "overview" function when pressing the (window) super button.

Can I recreate this behavior in Windows 8.1 ? If yes, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Fedora’s functionality.

Comment: i think Stephen refers to "exposé" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expos%C3%A9_clone )

Comment: Yes, exposé is what I was looking for.
Thanks akira